# Why C++ Concepts return type requirement be a type-constraint and not also Primitive type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20

Hello everyone Concepts are now a part of C++20 standard and to play with it I basically wrote this example that I saw sometime back

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
concept Container= requires (T a){

    { a.size() } -> size_t;
    // others
}

template<Container Holder>
class Demo{};
int main(){


    Demo<std::vector<int>> d;


}
```

But on compiling the code  I got the following error

> error: return-type-requirement is not a type-constraint ( { a.size() } -> size_t;)

Later on i remembered that return type constraint cannot be a primitive type and changed the code with std::same_as

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
concept Container= requires (T a){

    { a.size() } -> std::same_as<size_t>;
    // others
}

template<Container Holder>
class Demo{};
int main(){

    Demo<std::vector<int>> d;

}
```

where std::same_as is itself a concept.

But why cant primitive types be used? I know that it breaks something in C++ but i am not able to remember it.

Comment: The expression to the right of `->` must be a "type constraint."  `std::same_as` is a type constrant.  `size_t` is not.  Are you asking why the design is this way?  Because that's probably off-topic.

Comment: Yes i wanna know why it has been designed this way .i remember that previously the syntax with primitive types was allowed but it interfered with some feature in C++ ( As far as i remember )

Comment: Did the old syntax break some code? Any references or examples would be a lot helpful

Comment: Language design archaeology is usually not a great fit for this site, but maybe someone will dig it up.

Comment: You might be thinking of http://wg21.link/p1452

Comment: Yup although not this paper actually  but some blog that mentioned the exact same thing. Thanks man

Comment: Can you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 10):

Because the semantics are ambiguous: does `{ a.size() } -> size_t` mean the result of `a.size()` is *convertible to* `size_t`, or `decltype(a.size())` is exactly *same as* `size_t`?

Thus, one must use a constraint to make the intent clear (`convertible_to` for the former, `same_as` for the latter).

Comment: It should mean it's exactly the same, implicit conversions by default are bad. Now everyone has to write same_as<T> all over the place, it's as if the committee is deliberately engineering for verbosity.